# Quoted Printable - Decode .eml

Tags: java, character-encoding, decode, quoted-printable

i want decode some content of an .eml-Mail-File. The File contains Strings like "Gesch=C3=A4ftsbedingungen", it shoult be > "Geschäftsbedingungen"

```
reader = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(path)); 
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(reader);

while ((line = in.readLine()) != null)          
{ 
System.out.println(line); 
}
```

Im not sure how i do that. I try to use "MimeUtility", but i do not get along so.

```
MimeUtility test;
System.out.println(test.decode(line));
```

Answer (score 0):

**Note** : `MimeUtility` is an utility class so it contains all static methods so you should use

```
System.out.println(MimeUtility.decode(line));
```

Though I think you should use [`MimeUtility.decodeText`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeUtility.html#decodeText%28java.lang.String%29) or [`MimeUtility.decodeWord`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeUtility.html#decodeText%28java.lang.String%29) method or  [commons `MimeUtility.decodeText`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/apidocs/org/apache/commons/fileupload/util/mime/MimeUtility.html#decodeText%28java.lang.String%29) method.

Comment: How do you import MimeUtility?